# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an error that I kind of understand, but can't figure out to solve in the right way.

I have a MasterPage, from that MasterPage I call:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Tags"); %>
```

Tags is a strongly typed view that looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<JegManglerEn.Controllers.CategoryCount>>" %>
```

I return the PartialView like this:

```
return View("Tags", result);
```

where result is correct and of type:

```
List<CategoryCount>
```

The error is this:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JegManglerEn.Item]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[JegManglerEn.Controllers.CategoryCount]'.

So the setup is this:

MasterPage loads a View that takes a collection of JegManglerEn.Item AND also tries to load a PartialView that takes a collection of a JegManglerEn.Controllers.CategoryCount...but fails to do so.

I know it has something to do with the RenderPartial method because if I change it to RenderAction it's works great.

If you guys have the answer I get to skip looking at the MVC soruce or startup Reflector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call the single-parameter overload of Html.RenderPartial, you're implicitly passing the entire model of the parent view down to the partial. This doesn't work, as the model types expected by the views do not match.

The simplest way to get RenderPartial working in your context is to create a composite model type that contains both the Tags and the page model data, then call the overload where you pass a part of the parent model to the partial:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Tags", Model.Tags);
```

That being said, I think RenderAction is most likely the way to go here, as it makes it easier to avoid duplicate code in your controllers (of course assuming you're loading the tags data in the same way for all pages inheriting from the masterpage in question).

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<JegManglerEn.Controllers.CategoryCount>>
```

to

```
ViewUserControl<List<JegManglerEn.Controllers.CategoryCount>>
```