# how to create a List<T> in my data model MVC4 C# and start using it?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 project, I want to use in my data model a `List<bool>` to handle several checkboxes. So I wrote:

```
List<bool> multiple { get; set; }
```

But obviously this won't work at all because I didn't instantiate the list with a specific size using the keyword `new`. How can I do that without throwing away the getter and setter of course?

Answer (score 2):

In the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for the object, instantiate the property as a new list.  As for setting the size, that's not necessary with a list:

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.multiple = new List<bool>();
}
```

Comment: I got this error:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "MyApp.Models.MyModel 'but this dictionary requires a model item of type" System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1 [MyApp.Models.MyModel]"`
what is its origin?

Comment: See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293344/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type

Comment: I didn't understand, I don't use this method at all (`Html.RenderPartial(...)`)

Comment: I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to use the list in my controller. How can I fix it?